# Best way to store large data in mysql

Tags: mysql

I need to store large amount of data every hour in the database. What kind of data? Text data.

What is the best way? Store on multiple table or 1 large table?

Edit: I just said, large text data. 10000 times the word "data"

Every hour a new line is added like:
hour - data

Edit 2: Just because you can't understood the question, and also i said, "EVERY HOUR", so you imagine every hour for the next 10 years a new line will be created, does not mean its not a readable question.

Comment: not everything has to go into a database ...

Comment: Large: Data in multiple pieces or just a one huge piece?

Comment: Please define what is the data to be stored, for how many records you are talking about and how big is one entry.

Comment: Regarding your edit. One record every hour for 10 years is small data in terms of number of records. 10000 times the word data gives are some hint about the MB size of a record. It does not give us anything about what data is or how you will use it, but you can store it in one table. If table size is a problem, you can partition the table. You can also use merge table between myisam and archive, if the old data won't be updated....

Comment: @keepwalking I Think you forgot that you are asking for help. I would be more polite if expecting help from others. Good luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is better to use a database that is not used by anything else but whatever uses the data (as it is a lot of text data and may slow down SQL queries) and create seperate tables for each category of data. 
Ad@m

Answer (score 2):

Use a column of datatype 'text', 'mediumtext', or 'largetext' according to your needs.

See: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/blob.html

Alternatively, you could just output the data to a file.  They are more appropriate for logging large amounts data that may not need to be accessed often - which it seems like this might be.

Answer (score 2):

MySql have added many feature in MySql 5.7. Now you can do it in many way.

> Oracle like Big Data is now Integrating in MySQL.
>
> MySql have Unlocked New Big Data Insights with MySQL & Hadoop.

**Soluation 1:** You can use MySQL as a Document Store. There are possible to store many many object as JSON. It highly recommended and Extendable.

> MySQL Document Store = (MySql + NoSql).
>
> X Dev API will help to produce JSON with SQL and CRUD operation over X
>   Protocol. Also there is possible to maintain X Session.

It will be best for transparent data sanding and sharing for chat application or group Application.

**Soluation 2:** `MySql Sysbench: Read Only` is another best solution. It will be very very fast and scalable to make group chat Application.

**Soluation 3:** Use `MySql 5.7 : InnoDB, NoSql with Memcached API` which will interact directly with storage engine InnoDB. It is 6X faster than MySql 5.6.

> Still Now FaceBook is using this technology. Because it is very fast.

For more details:

```
https://www.mysql.com/news-and-events/web-seminars/introducing-mysql-document-store/
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/document-store-setting-up.html
About Big Data: https://www.oracle.com/big-data/index.html
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1Dk517M-_7o
```